# How can we set permissions in Powerapps such that the creator of an application only can access the application within the enivironment?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection, powerapps-selected-items

In Microsoft PowerApps within a environment there will be many users. each one create their own application. in that case i need that , a single user should only see the application created by him within the environment.How can we set that permission?

Answer (score 0):

By default, a PowerApp is ONLY visible to its Owner.

**As long as the app is...:**

- a *Canvas* app (for some reason, *Model-driven* apps are visible to the whole env)
- and not shared with anyone

...it will not be visible to others.